# Share Redis Db among many users

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, shared-cache

If I store some data on my redis cache on my machine. Then is that data accessible to other people on their machines or the redis db is limited to one user only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you can share your Redis database with as many users as you want, provided you open up the network to your endpoint and port.

Note there is no Access Control List in Redis before version 6. Redis 6 is just out as release candidate 1 a few days ago. If you require ACL you may consider it if you are ok working with an RC1.

You can configure a Redis password, but it is one password for all users - shared. You can ask clients to also identify themselves by providing a name, but **it is an honor system**. Again, there is no ACL before Redis 6.

You can also use the firewall (network security) to limit what machines can connect to your instance.

Take a look at https://redis.io/topics/security for more on security.

To learn about Redis 6 ACL see https://redis.io/topics/acl